# Proguard R8 warnings

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-r8

Getting these warning while using r8

```
Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLParameters (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLSocket (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 5 other contexts)
Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.<init>())
Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version (referenced from: boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int))
Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt (referenced from: boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int) and 4 other contexts)
Missing class org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier (referenced from: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$DisabledHostnameVerifier)
Missing class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List))
Missing class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.openjsse.net.ssl.OpenJSSE (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.<init>())
```

Tried using this but it did not work.

```
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
```

Comment: which jdk did you use?

Answer (score 16):

Actually this seems to be now fixed in OkHttp version `4.11.0`, released on April 2023: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-bom

I had the same issue and once I updated to this version, the build goes through successfully

Comment: I had the same problem, after 2 days of trying, I downgraded OkHttp from version 5.0.0-alpha.1 to version 4.12.0 and the problem was solved. I am very surprised.

Answer (score 10):

Fixed in okhttp 5
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6258

Add rulse from
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/okhttp/src/jvmMain/resources/META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro

```
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.openjsse.**
```

Comment: It is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Missing classes when compiling with R8 means that there are references to these classes in the input, but they have no definition in the input neither in the program itself, on the classpath or in the library/bootclasspath (`android.jar` when building Android apps). The `-keep` rule is used to keep classes already present in the input, and has no effect on missing classes (it might actually end up giving more missing classes).

To silence the warnings about missing classes the `-dontwarn` directive can be used, e.g.:

```
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLParameters
```

Before going ahead with adding `-dontwarn` make sure that the missing classes are not due to a missing dependency, which might end up causing runtime failures.

Comment: This seems the most informative answer. However, `-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLParameters` shows up in red in Android Studio, with "Unresolved class name" complaint. Using `**` avoids this problem and you end up with much cleaner proguard file, with just one `-dontwarn` line per library. For example: `-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**`

Comment: Yes, the red squiggles under a `-dontwarn` class might not be the best UI, as `-dontwarn` is often used for classes which are missing. I have opened https://issuetracker.google.com/328166444 on this issue.

Comment: The issue with the squiggles was already fixed in Android Studio Iguana, https://issuetracker.google.com/301246673.