# Extract the apk file Missing classes detected while running R8 flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73748946/proguard-r8-warnings. Can you provide your pubspec.yaml in the description? I wonder if a plugin you are using dependences on an older version of OKHttp.